# Redirect adding 1/2 second delay! -- moving from old O365 APIs to Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have existing code that uses the old Office365 API. In that API, the very first step before OAuth was to use the Discovery API to identify the appropriate end points for the API for the user signing in. Different user domains had different end-points (something like https://foo.my-sharepoint.com/.... Subseqently, the API would use REST methods against that end-point.

Now we are trying to move to the Graph API. And we find that performance is significantly worse. The root cause seems to be that each API call to the graph API leads to a 302 redirect after a 1/2 second delay! So instead of initially looking up the appropriate endpoint, this seems to happen inefficiently on every single API call.

Has anyone else seen this? Any workarounds? This is effectively making our system way slower.

Some details requested by @baywet ...

The original GET request is to fetch the content of a file identified by file path (constructed by the C# SDK): 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/appsheet//NationalParks.xlsx:/content

After a 0.6 second delay, it gets a 302 redirect to:
https://1track-my.sharepoint.com/personal/praveen_1track_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=d9019efd-887e-4c6c-80ce-8399afa9131c&Translate=false&tempauth=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.Z0VsdldZTnBsY2dHVzJxSEtndTFpbzd6MDFtK3lvc0NRZU02dWxPVHVjTT0&ApiVersion=2.0

"1track-my.sharepoint.com" is the actual O365 site. The old API would figure this out during the initial discoveryAPI phase so you pay the cost of the lookup once and then directly hit the appropriate endpoint.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the graph endpoints you're trying to hit?

Comment: @baywet Updated the post to include the information on the endpoints

Comment: Sorry Praveen for the late response.  Can you add some additional information please and we can take a look at the trace logs and see what's going on here.  What we need for the request is a client-request-id and an associated timestamp.

Comment: Hi @DanKershaw-MSFT , sure I can get that. But really this seems to be the case on every single call so getting a specific client-request-id and timestamp may not really be useful. This redirect appears to be by design rather than an anomaly on a particular call. As I explained in the original post, I get that the graph API is abstracting the fact that each O365 domain has a different physical endpoint. However, if it is doing this via a 0.5 second delayed redirect on each call, it is really problematic.

Comment: @PraveenSeshadri - which old Office365 API are you moving from? The direct OneDrive REST API documented at https://dev.onedrive.com/items/download.htm also returns a 302/redirect on the initial call.

Comment: @PraveenSeshadri Are the files you are downloading all in the same folder? If you get the list of items in the folder from MSGraph, you'll have individual download URLs for each item and avoid the 302 redirect. If you are downloading a lot of items all in the same place, this can be a faster way to do it.

Comment: Hi @MarekRycharski, it is the original OneDrive for Business API where you first use the discovery API to find the REST endpoints for the user, and then use web apis like {endPoint}/files/getByPath('foo/bar/foobar.xlsx')/content

Comment: @RyanGregg, we have persisted the path to a specific file. We need to read it at sometime in the future. We're using the standard C# GraphAPI SDK and constructing an IDriveRequestBuilder, giving it the path, and asking to read the file. I don't see how we could use the download URL for this (even if we fetched it and saved it along with the path, the download URL is short-lived so this won't work).

Comment: @RyanGregg, any update? Thanks

Comment: @PraveenSeshadri - Like Dan has mentioned - it would be good to have a couple of client-request-id and an associated timestamps for a few of these calls to allow us to track down these requests and better understand the delays

Comment: @Andre-Teixera here are two client request ids. Each of them is a request for the same file, executed within a couple of minutes of each other. Each of them 302 redirects after a delay. We observe an average delay of 0.5 seconds on every such call. So tack on the additional 0.5 seconds for the actual call after redirect, and it is a minimum of 1 second to do a simple file operation.

client-request-id: c2628b1f-8d6d-4fb0-9016-ee8a7b6c1429
client-request-id: 8c2566ad-9c0e-4aea-b4ee-b8c711289943

Comment: @AndreTeixeira misspelt your handle in my previous response. Sorry